# URL not found no CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou utilizando o Bake do CakePHP para facilitar o desenvolvimento, analisei os Models e Controllers que ele gerou e estão ok. Segue linha do método index em um dos controllers.

```
public function index() {
    $this->Category->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('categories', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Quando abro no navegador dá erro `404 NOT FOUND.`

Segui alguns tutoriais e ativei o `mod_rewrite` mas não funcionou.

A versão do CakePHP é 2.3.1, também testei na 2.9.8.

Answer (score 0):

Na index apenas faça

```
**Public function index(){
(E ao acessar a index ele pede para vc criar uma View e em seguida crie uma função de paginate separada)
}**
```

Você está fazendo dessa forma :

```
public function index() {
    $this->Category->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('categories', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Está passando um $this->set em 'Categorias' está setando para consumir em uma View mais de fato quem é categorias, ele não esta entendo isso tenta passar assim:

```
**public function index() {
    $categoria = $this->Category->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('categoria', $categoria);
}**
```

Aqui estou passando que a variável `$categoria` contem `$this->Category->recursive = 0;`
em seguida eu seto essa variavel com um nome para consumir em outro CTP.